# install WSO2 Private PaaS on HP Helion Public Cloud

Tags: wso2

does anyone has any experience/idea about installing WSO2 Private PaaS 4.0.0 on HP Helion public cloud.

I followed the instructions of the "Automated Product Configuration" in the WSO2 webpage, and

everything seems fine, I came to the last step "sudo ./boot.sh"

the display prompts the following:

WSO2 Private PaaS product configuration completed.
Do you need to setup WSO2 BAM (Business Activity Monitor) as a core service? [y/n] y
Do you need to start WSO2 Private PaaS? [y/n] y
Starting BAM core service...
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
Starting Gitblit core service...
nohup: ignoring input and redirecting stderr to stdout
Starting WSO2 Private PaaS server as root user...

the process hangs here. 
I tried several times, and with the same results

By the way I have selected Openstack as the IaaS opotions (see below screen catch)

Enter your IaaS. vCloud, EC2 and OpenStack are the currently supported IaaSs. Enter "vcloud" for vCloud, "ec2" for EC2 and "os" for OpenStack: os
You selected OpenStack. 
Enter OpenStack identity : 10976979403672:K7B6GX5A6AXJX7VXGFML
Enter OpenStack credentials : 
Enter OpenStack jclouds_endpoint : https://region-a.geo-1.compute.hpcloudsvc.com/v2/10976979403672
Enter the region of the IaaS you want to spin up instances : US West
Enter OpenStack keypair name : paas-dev
Enter OpenStack security groups : paas-dev-sg
Enter OpenStack cartridge base image id : agent-base

thanks

Comment: I edit the screen prompt so it is more readable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 Private PaaS 4.0.0 only supports Amazon EC2, OpenStack and VCloud. 
Private PaaS uses Apache jClouds to talks to the underlying IaaS. Therefore it is possible to extend it to support HP Helion since jClouds supports Helion according to [1]. But that is not yet implemented.

[1] https://jclouds.apache.org/reference/providers/